# Allow hotlinking but redirect when I am my own referrer!

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, hotlinking

I want to, using htaccess, allow hotlinking BUT if someone views an image on my site I want to redirect them to a "hosted" version of the image where I display my navigation etc.

So essentially anyone hotlinking from an external site will not be affected but if someone views the image on my server directly i.e. www.domain.com/image.jpg itll redirect.  I also want to make sure I can display images correctly from within my site too.

Can anyone help?

EDIT: Here is the code I currently have

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.jpg$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} =""
RewriteRule ^userpics/covers/(.*).jpg$ /view/$1.html [R=301]

RewriteRule ^view/(.*).html$ /view.html?img=$1 [L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|png|gif)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://yoursite\.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ url_to_script?img=$1
```

You could simplify

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://yoursite\.com/.*$ [NC]
```

to just

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} yoursite\.com [NC]
```

And the rule can be written as

```
 RewriteRule (.*) url_to_script?img=$1
```

if you need to include the path to the image in your parameter.

Comment: I have tried this and it works if you open the image directly, but if you link arrive at the image via a website link the HTTP_REFERRER is not null so you see the image properly - what can be done about this?

Comment: @Chris: This will only rewrite if the referrer is your website. If you access the image directly, or if you click a link from another site, it won't do anything except give you the image. I just tried this on my server and it works as expected. Only if I click a link from my own domain am I redirected.

Comment: I have updated my question with what I currently have based on a combination of all answers.  It works perfectly except for when a referrer is set, is there another way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: @Chris: You want to check that the referrer ${HTTP_REFERER} is set to your domain. The condition in my answer does that.

Comment: Jason - if the image was linked to from another site then, say google images, then it wouldnt redirect would it?

Comment: @Chris: No, if there is no referrer, or the referrer is not your domain, it will not redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You should use mod_rewrite, if the HTTP_REFERRER is empty then redirect to `/image-with-nav.php?image=$1`
Try something like this
`RewriteEngine on`

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$`

`.* image-with-nav.php?image=$1 [L]`

Comment: This is pretty much what I want but if I click a link on a site that takes me directly to the image wouldnt the referrer be set then?

Comment: Well yes, but that's the trade off, there's no 100% to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Now, what you need to check is the referrer because the URL is always the URL of your image, since it is a http request. You could go with something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|png|gif)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} =""
RewriteRule (.*) http://someurl.com [R=301]
```

Comment: Wouldnt the referrer be set if you goto the image from another page though?